# Printing all occurences of a string in a file using regular expressions using php

Tags: php, regex, string, file

i am writing a code that will print all instances of a string from a file of about 500 pages. 
This is some of the code:

```
$file = "serialnumbers.txt";
$file_open = fopen($file, 'r');

$string = "\$txtserial";
$read = fread($file_open,'8000000');
$match_string = preg_match('/^$txtserial/', $read, $matches[]=null);
for($i = 0; sizeof($matches) > $i; $i++)
{
echo "<li>$matches[$i]</li>";
}
```

All of the serial numbers start with "$txtserial" followed by about 10 numerical characters, some of them separated by comma(,). Example: $txtserial0840847276,8732569089.
I am actually looking for a way to print every instances of the $txtserial with the following numerical characters excluding the comma(,).  Though I have used regular expressions but if there is any other method to employ i will also be grateful. I just want to get this done in the quickest possible time

Comment: is `$txtserial` always at the start of a line?

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem here where you are trying to create a regex using string variable:

```
$match_string = preg_match('/^$txtserial/', $read, $matches[]=null);
```

You can use:

```
$match_string = preg_match('/^' . preg_quote($txtserial) . '/', $read, $matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this example using `preg_match_all()` function:

```
$txtserial = 'MSHKK';
$read = 'MSHKK1231231231,23
MSHKK1231231
txtserial123123109112
MSHKK1231231111,123123123';

$match_string = preg_match_all('/(?:^|(?<=[\n\r]))('.preg_quote($txtserial).'\d{10})\b/', $read, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Output:

```
[0] => MSHKK1231231231
[1] => MSHKK1231231111
```

It is basically picking the portions which are starts with the value that `$txtserial` holds and followed by `10` digits.